# Woocommerce Hook woocommerce_get_price how to used in product list?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i used the Woocommerce for shopping cart. i want to change price of product in listing page. i used this hook for change product price.

```
woocommerce_get_price
```

This is my function.

```
add_action('woocommerce_get_price','change_price_regular_member', 10, 2);
function change_price_regular_member($price, $productd){
    return $price*2/100;
}
```

i want to change price of all product in listing page.

But this function is not working is return first product price in every product price.

how can i used this hook to change every product price perfect?

Thank You.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When i test your code, all prices in my listing change.
Maybe you got a problem with sales prices. The `WC_PRODUCT` class has different functions (including filter to get a price depending on it's sales status). The `get_price_html` uses the `get_regular_price` or `get_price_suffix` function, etc.

Try:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','change_price_regular_member', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_regular_price','change_price_regular_member', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_sale_price','change_price_regular_member', 10, 2);
```

You could also try an extension like http://club.orbisius.com/products/wordpress-plugins/woocommerce-extensions/orbisius-flex-price-woocommerce/.

**update**

> Your Code is not working every where when i place order through paypal

It seems the paypal gateway use the order class instead of the product class to calculate prices. In `./includes/class-wc-order.php` you will find functions such as `get_item_subtotal()` which has a filter `apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_amount_item_subtotal', $price, $this );`. Try to use these, for instance:

```
          add_filter('woocommerce_order_amount_item_subtotal','change_price_regular_member', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Hey Bass Can you help me to know how to fire that filter on checkout page?

Comment: AFAIK these filters (add them to your function.php) are also applied to the checkout

Comment: Dear Your Code is not working every where when i place order through paypal that return original price please help?

Comment: Bass, please add an "l" as your filter ends in "subtota" where it should be "subtotal"

Answer (score 5):

`woocommerce_get_price` is deprecated since version 3.0.0

Use `woocommerce_product_get_price` instead.